# Where to find the complete documentation about BMP file structure?

Tags: structure, bmp

As you know from the question, I am trying to find a complete documentation with high definition about the BMP file structure. I tried Wikipedia but that didn't help at all. Can you mention any site/ebook that provides the mentioned information to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the documentation in Wikipedia isn't sufficient, you may like to try the entry in [the Encyclopedia of Graphics File Formats](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm) or the entry at [fileformats.archiveteam.org](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/BMP).